# AngularJS content in HTML loaded through JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am loading an HTML file through JS, this file is containing AngularJS content which doesn't work.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp.firstElement" ng-controller="ControllerOne" id="firstElement">
   AngularJS content
</div>
<div ng-app="MyApp.secondElement" ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
   AngularJS content
</div>

<script src="loadContent.js"></script>
```

loadContent.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstElement").load("includedContent.html");
})
```

includedContent.html:

```
<md-sidenav>
    <md-content>
     ...
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
```

As you can see, I have a `ng-app` in each `div`. The angular scripts & css are included in the page. But the loaded angular content isn't working.

The only way I found to make it work, is to directly paste the code from `includedContent.html` into the main HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp.firstElement" ng-controller="ControllerOne" id="firstElement">
    <md-sidenav>
        <md-content>
         ...
        </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
</div>
<div ng-app="MyApp.secondElement" ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
   AngularJS content
</div>

<script src="loadContent.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple ng-app signatures? There should be only one

Comment: I work this way 'cause I want my code to be very clear, so I separate into multiple app. It supposed to have only one app per page. But in order to make smooth switch animation I decided to merge the two pages.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work that way.

1/ You just need one ng-app attribute (ideally on your html element)

2/ If you want to load a template you should use directive and not load it using external .js file.

3/ Try not to use Jquery and stick to Angular. What's the point in having Angular when you want to mainpulate DOM using Jquery

Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap.

When reading about directives have a look at 'directive definition object' properties ex. template/templateUrl (that's where you can get you template) and compile post funnction (aka. link function) that will allow you to interact with your element which is a Jquery object (or JqLite object if you don't have your Jquery loaded before angular).

Comment: Ok it's noticed, thank you for your answer. I work this way 'cause I want my code to be very clear, so I separate into multiple app. It supposed to have only one app per page. But in order to make smooth switch animation I decided to merge the two pages.

Answer (score 0):

No need to load HTML using JS. HTML can be loaded in angular way using "ng-include='PATH_TO_FILE'" built in angular directive

```
<div ng-app="MyApp.firstElement" ng-controller="ControllerOne" id="firstElement" ng-include="'includedContent.html'">
   AngularJS content
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome, you can also like this answer to help  others.

Comment: I cannot. I don't have enough rep.